# Server SSL incomplete chain (Inmotion server)

Tags: ssl

I have installed a ssl certificate via WHM on one of my domain. Site is working with https://xyz.com.

However it is not working with https://www.xyz.com. I have checked the certificate and it is for www version as well. After some research it appears to be incomplete chain issue. I had no idea how to resolve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

A certificate can contain a special *Authority Information Access* extension ([RFC-3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280)) with URL to issuer's certificate. Most browsers can use the AIA extension to download missing intermediate certificate to complete the certificate chain. But some clients (mobile browsers, OpenSSL) don't support this extension, so they report such certificate as untrusted.

You can solve the *incomplete certificate chain* issue manually by concatenating all certificates from the certificate to the trusted root certificate (exclusive, in this order), to prevent such issues. Note, the trusted root certificate should not be there, as it is already included in the system’s root certificate store.

You should be able to fetch intermediate certificates from the issuer and concat them together by yourself. I have written a script to automate the procedure, it loops over the AIA extension to produce output of correctly chained certificates. https://github.com/zakjan/cert-chain-resolver